What happened to the other answer in this question?
The question in question is this: What is the classical Chinese meaning of 或?
There was another answer by a new user on there, but it's not there anymore. What happened to it? Did it get mod-deleted or did the author delete it himself? I thought it was a good answer, except for the missing part mentioned in my comment. 
P.S We need a tag for deleted-answers :). 

Probably deleted by the author

It is deleted by the author.
You would be able to view deleted posts once you reach 2000 reputation.
加油!

Thanks. 顽张って! haha :). Still got a long way to go.
